# Play Framework: Run single selenium test on the command line (headless browser)

Tags: java, selenium, playframework

I can run a single selenium test in play's browser UI, however, is it possible to execute a play selenium test on the command line?

Obviously if I run `play auto-test` it will execute all my selenium tests (as well as my junit tests).  Is there a way that I could tell Play to execute just a single selenium test on the command line to check whether it works using the headless browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think it's possible to do so with the current play framework,

but see how auto-test works on 
https://github.com/playframework/play/blob/master/modules/testrunner/src/play/modules/testrunner/FirePhoque.java .

It get the play test lists on `/@tests.list` , maybe you could try to override it providing what you want to test.

Anyway, I don't see the usecase of testing only one test in a headless browser.

Comment: duuuhhh for developing it!